# FindMinimum with constraint produces incorrect results

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

Issuing the following:

```
FindMinimum[{x, ((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3) <= 10^-10}, {x, 2}]
```

produces a value of 13.1686 . The constraint for that value is: 1.50531*10^-7 . I get the same result for an exponent of -20 or even -100 . Changing the starting point, even as far as 200, produced similar results.

I have used `FindMinimum` for *many* other examples, with consistent success -- until now.

Where is my error?

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the answer is zero (from @user64494 's answer).  But all values immediately surrounding that value are complex.  Wouldn't that isolated real point be expected to cause `FindMinimum` some problems?  Your function is not monotonic over all values of $x$.

Comment: `Plot[((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3), {x, 2, 20}]` seems to be pretty well-behaved, monotonically decreasing, and (obviously) a nice negative derivative.

Comment: It is well-behaved in that range of $x$ values.  But the global (real) minimum occurs when $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `NMinimize`

```
mini=NMinimize[{x, ((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3) <= 10^-10, x > 2 }, x ]
(*{17.7168, {x -> 17.7168}}*)

((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3) /. mini[[2]]  
(*1.*10^-10*)
```

To make `FindMinimum` work the constraint has to be modified( don't know why):

```
FindMinimum[{x, Log[10, ((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3)] <= -10,2 < x < 20}, {x, 2} ] 
(*{17.7168, {x -> 17.7168}}*)
```

Comment: 1) TYVM.
2) I was using `FindMinimum` as it finds _local_ minima. I would prefer that.
3) With your way, I was able to rid of the `NMinimize::incst` warning but adding the partially-undocumented range for the initial range of the second argument.
4) Stil this only worked until 10^-27. After that, the results with unchanged and garbage.
5) I still do not understand how `FindMinimum` finishes with an incorrect result, without even a warning. Is this a bug to report?

Comment: Your function decreases monotonically for `x>2, x->Infinity` and you are looking for the smallest x for which the constraint holds! What's the reason to expect local minimas?

Comment: But my _function_ is just the monotonic increasing `x`, with that monotonic decreasing _constraint_. So why would this not work (like it does for all of the dozens of other constraints I used)?

Comment: It works as expected, `NMinimize` evaluates the unique solution!

Comment: I am sorry that I was not clear enough. I was asking why `FindMinimum` does not behave correctly.

Comment: `FindMinimum` has problems with the very small constraint, see my modified answer.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: `FindMinimum[{x, Log[10, ((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3)] <= -10, 
  0 < x < 20}, {x, 2}]` performs `{17.7168, {x -> 17.7168}}`.. The logarithmization leads to a non-equivalent inequality (see  school textbooks on math).

Comment: Sorry couldn't  find my schoolbook `0.1<0.5` => `Log[0.1]=-2.30< -0.693147=Log[0.5]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: In particular, `Log[0]` does not exist.

Comment: As well as `Log[10, ((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3) /. x -> 2/3]`.

Comment: @user64494 Your two comments are completely dispensable...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, thank you for this `Log10` insight and trick.

Comment: @AharonNaiman You're welcome, your question was very interesting!

Comment: Aharn Naiman & Ulrich Neumann: I repeat `FindMinimum[{x, Log[10, ((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3)] <= -10,    0 < x < 20}, {x, 2}]` performs an incorrect answer `{17.7168, {x -> 17.7168}}`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at the result of

```
Reduce[((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3) <= 10^-10, x, Reals]
```

> x==0||x==1/2||2/3<x<=0.667[Ellipsis]||x>=17.7[Ellipsis]

Then `FindMinimum` does its best by

```
FindMinimum[{x,Reduce[((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3) <= 10^-10, x, Reals]}, {x,2}]
```

> `{0.666667, {x -> 0.666667}}`

and `Minimize` does its best by

```
Minimize[{x, Reduce[((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3) <= 10^-10, x, Reals]}, x]
```

> `{0, {x -> 0}}`

Comment: `NMinimize[{x, 
  Reduce[((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3) <= 10^-10, x, Reals]}, x]` results in `{0., {x -> 0.}}`.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. You have added `Reduce` which according to the manual page: "The result of Reduce[expr,vars] always describes exactly the same mathematical set as expr." But why then are your and my results different? And, my result does _not_ have a constraint of less than 10^-10?

Comment: @AharonNalman: Yes `((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3) <= 10^-10` and `Reduce[((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3) <= 10^-10, x, Reals]` define the same sets over the reals, but not the same sets  over the complexes.as `RegionPlot[
 Re[(2 (x + I*y + 1)/(3 (x + I*y) - 2))^(4 (x + I*y) - 3)] <= 
  10^-10, {x, -1, 20}, {y, -1, 1}]` shows. Also the result of `Reduce` have a simpler form which is more convenient for `FindMinimum`. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @AharonNalman: Also see `ContourPlot[  Im[(2 (x + I*y + 1)/(3 (x + I*y) - 2))^(4 (x + I*y) - 3)] ==    0, {x, -1, 20}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50]`. These plots together show complex solutions of the inequality `((2 x + 1)/(3 x - 2))^(4 x - 3) <= 10^-10.`.

Comment: Thank you again for these explanations. I have tried to introduce `x` being real other ways (`Assuming`, as a constraint, with `Re`, etc.), to no avail. I am still stymied how `FindMinimum` can return a value for `x`, with the constraint not at all fulfilled.

Comment: @AharonNaiman: I prefer exact formulations over messy words. Can you elaborate your "I am still stymied how FindMinimum can return a value for x, with the constraint not at all fulfilled."? TIA.

Comment: I am sorry that my words seem to be "messy" to you. All I am stating, as in my initial question, is that the output of 13.1686 from `FindMinimum` produces a constraint value of 1.50531*10^-7 which is clearly larger than the requirement of being less than 10^-10 .